# surfaceplot with matplotlib over points xyz

Tags: python, matplotlib, geometry-surface

I'm trying to plot a surface over several points it should look like a deformed sphere. 
I used the scatter function and plotted the points, but the surface function is not working (the window is empty).

To plot the surface, I think i need a mesh function. I try ed to mash x,y,z but it was not working. How i can generate the code, to put a surface over my points?. 
Thanks for helping me.

I have the points xyz stored in a list. They are describing a deformed sphere and i have to plot somthing like this

[image]
<sub>(source: [iop.org](http://ej.iop.org/images/1367-2630/12/3/033037/Full/nj332389fig1.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

This question is hard to answer without any sample code of what you're doing, you might want to edit it to include a working example.

I suppose you are using the `mplot3d` class, have you checked the examples that are provided online [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/trisurf3d_demo.html), [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/wire3d_animation_demo.html), and [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/wire3d_demo.html)? These to me look like what you're trying to produce.

Comment: exactly Im using mplot3 and i now the examples but i need something like a deformed sphere (i edit to my Question)